# True/false :If a set $A$ is connected, then so interior $A^o$ is also connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the  following statement is true/false ?

If a  set $A$  is  connected, then so interior  $A^o$ is  also  connected.

My attempt : I think this statement is true I have not  found  any  contradiction  I was thinking about $A = [0,1]$, or $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not true. Consider union of two closed balls in $\mathbb R^{2}$ touching each other at one point. The interior of this set is the union of the corresponding open balls. These two open balls are non-empty disjoint open sets and their union is not connected by the very definition of connectedness.

Comment: im not getting  as union of two closed ball is connected  But  how  can we said that their interior is disconnected  can u elaborate more .....sir

Comment: @jasmine I have added an explanation.

Comment: While correct and instructive this is also yet another post spoon feeding a solution to an assignment. Follow the history of this asker to see it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for this information. I will avoid doing  this from now on.